# ContextLoaderListener in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I am new in spring boot

I am trying to configure `ContextLoaderListener` and regiter a Bean in the listener, so that I can use it in two different `DispatcherServlet`.

I have done this successfully in **spring mvc** with `JavaConfig` but In **spring-boot** I am unable to configure `ContextLoaderListener`

Please Help

Comment: `public class CustomWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

 @Override
 public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
  AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
  rootContext.register(RootConfiguration.class);
  ContextLoaderListener contextLoaderListener = new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext);...... `

Comment: You don't really need a `ContextLoaderListener`,... Just add your bean to the configuration, add a `DispatcherServlet` and you are done. \

Answer (score 0):

add `@ServletComponentScan` to the main method